# bash shell program

Tags: bash, shell, brace-expansion

```
!/bin/bash
echo Enter the num
read n
for i in { 1..10 }
do
m=$(( n*i ))
echo "$i * $n" = $m
done
```

i got error as

**for: 8: Illegal number: {**
kindly suggest a solution

Comment: please format the code as code.

Answer (score 5):

do it like this

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the num: " n
for i in {1..10}
do
    m=$(( n*i ))
    echo "$i * $n" = $m
done
```

the shebang is wrong, and don't leave space in brace expansion eg `{0..10}`, not `{ 0..10 }`

Comment: Could you please also tell me how could we do it in ksh.{0..10} is not valid is ksh

Comment: @benjamin You could always use the standard seq command like: "for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo $i; done"

Comment: @benjamin, my ksh version supports brace expansion. you can try `ksh -o braceexpand ` or `set -o braceexpand` in your script.

Answer (score 1):

This works in bash:

```
for (( i=1; i<=10; i++ )); do
    # ...
done
```